# Can anyone explain the below code especially the arguments (index)=>(e)=>

Tags: reactjs, frontend

I am a bit new to react, so I came across this code, The thing I didn't understand about this code is two arguments `(index) => (e) => ..` What does this mean ?

```
// App.js
const updateState = (index) => (e) => {
  const newArray = data.map((item, i) => {
    if (index === i) {
      return { ...item, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
    } else {
      return item;
    }
  });
  setData(newArray);
  };
```

Comment: It's a function whose result is a function; `updateState(some_index)` is a function that takes an argument `e` and proceeds to evaluate the bit in curly brackets. Read about higher-order functions in your favourite JavaScript books.

Answer (score 1):

Its a part of closure.  [Refer](https://atomizedobjects.com/blog/quick-fixes/what-do-multiple-arrow-functions-mean-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Simply%20put%2C%20the%20use%20of%20multiple%20arrow%20functions,is%20provided%2C%20then%20it%20will%20return%20that%20function.) this article.

Answer (score 1):

it's a function which returns a function.
It's equivalent to

```
const updateState = (index) => {
  const func = (e) => {
    const newArray = data.map((item, i) => {
      if (index === i) {
        return { ...item, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    setData(newArray);
  }
  return func;
}
```

So this could be called for example like:

```
updateState(1)({foo:'bar'})
// index === 1
// e === {foo:'bar'}
```

or

```
const updateStateAtIndex = updateState(1);
const result = updateStateAtIndex({foo: 'bar')}
```

In your case, `e` is an event, so I assume this is used in some kind of dynamic forms :)